# qtip clone function & Applying event on button in content

Tags: jquery, qtip

I have created a form inside of a QTIP and i have called the qtip functions for all the SVG elements. So to display the forms correctly I clone the content and the forms get displayed correctly. Now inside the form I want a button to change some form attributes so I wrote a function which changes the form attributes in the button's onclick method. The problem is that the button changes the attribute of the form but it does not change.

I think the problem might be because I am cloning the content and hence the attributes dont get changed once they clone.
How should I solve this problem?

JSfiddle link to understand problem :- [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/r9yfw/21)
You can see in this example that i haven't applied the clone and all button works...
but qtip disappears after one or two time showing.....

and if i apply clone than button won't work at all...

Answer (score 0):

Content part something like:

```
content: {
    text: $('#menu').clone()
},
```

And click part:

```
$(".menuitem").live('click', function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Tested - it works.
You can think of ''delagete'' also for ''menuitem''

Comment: [Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/r9yfw/26/) As you can see that click method won't work here.to change the attribute properties.